# Application Stopped on GPS Location Request Programmatically in Released APK

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-gps

**Update**

Forgot to mention that this is a xamarin coding.

In case may help:
I changed my linking option in android options from none to sdk assemblies only
I also enabled proguard

---

I am having a problem regarding request of location but only in released apk, it  always says application has stopped. I tried to debug it and found the part where exception occured. My application works well in debug mode so i'm clueless why it hit an exception during released apk testing. Tested using Asus zenfone 3 Nougat and OPPO lollipop, same result (failed on release, no issue on debug).

Here is part of my code

```
    public void m4_setUpAllClickable()
    {
        try
        {
            btnEnableGPS.Click += delegate
            {
                enableGPSLocation();
            };
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }

    private async void enableGPSLocation()
    {
        try
        {
            GoogleApiClient
                googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .AddApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .Build();

            googleApiClient.Connect();

            LocationRequest
                locationRequest = LocationRequest.Create()
                    .SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy)
                    .SetSmallestDisplacement(LocationValues.minimunDisplacement)
                    .SetInterval(LocationValues.normalInterval)
                    .SetFastestInterval(LocationValues.fastestInterval);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder
                locationSettingsRequestBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .AddLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            locationSettingsRequestBuilder.SetAlwaysShow(false);

//****** -> Problem Occur in this part and I don't know why since it is going straight to app has stopped instead of catch exception
            LocationSettingsResult
                locationSettingsResult = await LocationServices.SettingsApi.CheckLocationSettingsAsync(
                    googleApiClient, locationSettingsRequestBuilder.Build());
//****** -> ends here

            if (locationSettingsResult.Status.StatusCode == CommonStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired)
            {
                locationSettingsResult.Status.StartResolutionForResult(this, 1);
            }
            else if (locationSettingsResult.Status.StatusCode == CommonStatusCodes.Success)
            {
                if (activitySource == "GPS Failed")
                {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_AssignedList));
                    StartActivity(intent);
                    FinishAffinity();
                }
                else if (activitySource == "GPS Disabled")
                {
                    Finish();
                }
            }
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Comment: what was the exception ?

Comment: 1) Review the `logcat` output to determine the cause 2) Do you have the Linker turned for Release builds?, if so turn it off and retest as it might be a class/method not found exception (review `logcat` to determine)

Comment: @SushHangover, do you mean about linker is the settings on android options using linking option sdk assemblies only? I also have my proguard enabled in case may helpt

Comment: @jace The "odds" are it is related to Linker and/or Proguard stripping classes/methods that are needed, you need to review the logcat output to determine that.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for help. I'll take a look if it is because of proguard and linker. I'll update my question for logcat tomorrow. I just have to out for now in my work .

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, What I did is to change linking option from sdk assemblies only to sdk and user assemblies but failed. I also tried changing it to none and it succeed :) Thanks a lot ! still my proguard is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Have you added proguard rules to your project?If not, try this and rerun your release build

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: I don't have touch in Xamarin. This link may help you https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/release-prep/proguard/

Answer (score 0):

As @SushiHangover suggested on comment, I tried to change my application linking option from sdk assemblies only to none and it works well on released apk. I don't know why in this tutorial : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/ it says to enable proguard and change the linking option from none to sdk assemblies only so I did to make my application smaller. It goes down from 66mb to 40mb so I thought its a good thing but the problem is that it cuts some classes my application need.

So far it's working without linking options and my proguard is still enabled. Thanks for the help !